# Tensor Flow Zoo Model Object Detection - Does size affect result?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I am watching the list of all [tensorflow2 Zoo Model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md).
Assuming that 640x640 is the size of image, I was wondering what happen if the input image is bigger than the model size.

For example if we use :

```
SSD ResNet50 V1 FPN 640x640 (RetinaNet50)
```

If `640x640` is the image size and the image we use as input got a size of 1915x1080, would it affect quality of object detection? If yes, should we use `SSD ResNet50 V1 FPN 1024x1024 (RetinaNet50)` in order to get higher performances?

If my assumption is false what means `640x640` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the age old question, "does size matter"?  Yes, it does.  A model that is trained on 640x640 images expects to receive only 640x640 images.  If you have an image of 1915x1080, it is your job to reduce that to 640x640 for classification.  Often, the biggest part of a classification app is munging varied input into the standard form the model expects.

YOU will have to decide how to shrink the image.  Do you need to maintain aspect ratio?  Do you leave black bars top and bottom?

And **do not assume** that the 1024 model necessarily does a better job than the 640 model.  It is very often the case that more detail simply confuses the classification.

Comment: Damn thanks, last question, which model should I use in order to detect object on images ?

Comment: There is no single answer.  Neural nets are strange things.  You're going to want to try some of them with your target data and see how they perform.